# chrome 10: third party cookies blocking not working as expected

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I've ticked "Block all third party cookies without exception" yet when I visit sites like http://www.washingtonpost.com, the page show Facebook activity of my friends.

In Firefox 4, if I untick "accept 3rd party cookies" and visit the same above pages, I don't see any FB info.  This is what I want in Chrome. How do I achieve this in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome 10? V8 is the current release with 9 in beta.

Comment: I'm on the dev channel so my version is :10.0.634.0 dev".

Comment: 1. If you tick the option in firefox, does it stop blocking fb info? if it keeps blocking, you might be having a "social media"-stuff blocking extension installed in addition. 2. Have you cleared chrome's cookies after starting to block? Perhaps the option retains old cookie access. 3. Use the inspectors to analyze the Facebook widget. iframes are probably allowed to use their domain's cookies still.